# Stack Overflow chat

Tags: chat

Does anybody out there have any idea what Stack Overflow use for their chat services?

I want to add a chat tab to my site navigation and display a whole-page chat interface.

Answer (score 4):

The software used for Stack Exchange chat is developed by the team themselves. I'm not 100% sure what technologies it uses, but given that the rest of the network is written in ASP.NET MVC it will be .NET based but there will be a lot of AJAX going on as well.

So there are two things that need to be in place for you to be able to use it:

1. Your site needs to be technologically compatible.
2. SOIS needs to be willing to sell the software.

I suspect that (at the moment) they won't be willing to sell so even if your site was compatible you wouldn't be able to use it.

Comment: Thanks. You answered my question. Don't want their software; just wanted to know what it is developed on.